# In the video game Control, what does this dialog by Ahti about "taking turns" mean?

Tags: control

At the 18:11 mark, the janitor, Ahti, says

> We take turns to come for a visit.

How can they "take turns to come for a visit"?

Answer (score 6):

Ahti often uses Finnish phrases translated to English word-for-word instead of using the appropriate English phrase. In this case the phrase is "vuoroin vieraissa"; the Finnish equivalent of "tit for tat" (or "you scratch my back and I'll scratch yours"<sup>[(1)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vuoroin_vieraissa_k%C3%A4yd%C3%A4%C3%A4n)</sup>). It simply means that he thinks Jesse owes him a favor after he did something for her.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that it's never revealed what he means by "we", much less by "take turns". It seems very possibly that the [janitor](https://control.fandom.com/wiki/Ahti) is a member of The Board, or at least affiliated with them. [thegamer](https://www.thegamer.com/control-ahti-trivia/) suggests that he may even be a god.

Personal conjecture:

> If Ahti exists in the Astral Plane as The Board does, then he may be projecting himself on to our plane. If that's the case, then other members of whatever group he belongs to may also be capable of projecting themselves.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/controlgame/comments/ho3ow1/random_question_about_ahti_possible_foundation/ has no answers, but some additional data.